# How does Kinesis support Avro?

Tags: avro, amazon-kinesis

Amazon Kinesis claims to support Avro files.

Avro files (looking at Avro 1.8 here) contain both the schema, and the data, for a particular file.

Meanwhile, Kinesis ingests many records, and glue them together into one big file.

If each record we put in, is a Avro file, and Kinesis glues these together into bigger files, then we'll have files with a zillion little schemas. This doesn't seem like it will be useful/valid/work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Nope, the avro library merges the schema. There's only one schema for the big file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, oakad, but where does this Avro library run? How do I tell Kinesis that my data is Avro, and it should merge each of my records, as opposed to just gluing the individual records together? Or does the avro library recognize multiple concatenated Avro files and do the merge when the file is finally read/opened after delivery?

Comment: You can exchange Avro messages without schema attached just fine, in fact most people do it like that (as long as you can recreate the schema somehow, via reflection or whatever).

Comment: Avro files, in fact, are just the messages glued together with schema prepended and some "sync markers" here and there. So you can safely "glue" messages together and read them one by one as long as schema is correct.

Comment: You should post the sum of these comments as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As oakad suggested in the comments, the standard Avro libraries will read multiple concatenated Avro files, and presumably concatenate the schemas. That's great for users who use the standard Avro libraries.

Unfortunately, the consumer that I'm writing to through Kinesis does not use the standard Avro library, but a private implementation of the specification, which does not seem to have this behavior.

Separately, writing lots of little Avro files, each with their own schema, for "gluing records together" in Kinesis is certainly not a very good use of storage space, so I think the Kinesis model combined with Avro isn't the right choice here.

Comment: I want to do something similar, but have never used AWS kinesis before. I have created a basic avro schema using Python and have a schema registry. I am looking at the AWS docs on Kinesis, but not sure how I upload those schemas for validation. I initially created it in the API Gateway as a model and have validation happen there.